# How to rotate an image continously?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to display an image which is rotating continuously until that form closes. This means that the image should keep on rotating. I am trying this sample in windows application with c#. I did an example that text in the label is moving by the following code:

```
label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + 5, label1.Location.Y);
```

It may be the text in the label must rotate not like moving horizontally or vertically.

Comment: This is what WPF is dessigned for, I think.

Comment: not in WPF.Using Windows applications

Comment: Then perhaps you *should* try WPF to do this. In WPF you only need to add a rotation transform to the label. In WinForms you need to draw the string using GDI+, taking care to delete any previous text strings before drawing the new one, avoid flickering by using double buffering etc

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the following steps:

- add an `angle` variable
- add a "canvas" control to your form, e.g. a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- override its [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event
- obtain its `Graphics` contex and set a rotation [transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.drawing.graphics.transform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use [`Rotation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/k7dwd0wc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method supplying the value of the `angle` variable.
- use label's [`DrawToBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, to render your label onto a panel
- modify `angle` and call first the [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/598t492a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then [`Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.control.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the control that owns the canvas you're drawing on (in this example - the `Panel`)

Your label shouldn't be added in the designer.

You can also use it without a label control is a simple text will suffice - you can just use the [`DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method then.

Comment: int angle = 90;
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Image i = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg");
            g.TranslateTransform((float)i.Width / 2, (float)i.Height / 2);
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            g.TranslateTransform(-(float)i.Width / 2, -(float)i.Height / 2);
            g.DrawImage(i, new Point(0,0));
            g.RotateTransform(360);

Comment: I wrote this code but it is not moving,it is static no motion in that

Comment: @user2897388 Why should it move when the angle is constant?

Comment: if the angle is 45 or 90 also it is not moving

Comment: which angle I should mention to move

Comment: @user2897388 There is only one angle here. Not sure what are you talking about. I've updated the answer with more details, perhaps this was what you were missing.

Comment: g.RotateTransform(angle);  here angle=90

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<Storyboard x :Key="sbSpin">
<DoubleAnimation
  Storyboard.TargetName="Spin"
  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
  From="0"
  To="360"
  RepeatBehavior="Forever"
  Duration="0:0:3" Completed ="DoubleAnimation_Completed" />
</Storyboard>
```

I wrote a series of blog posts on this recently:

http://pmichaelsdev.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/animation-in-xaml-part-3/

Comment: sorry to say that I am not using WPF

Comment: Although the question is about WinForms, this just shows how *easy* it is to do this with WPF. The equivalent GDI+ code is rather more convoluted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, we can add also 10 other answers showing how easy it can be done in other numerous technologies. It won't change the fact that they're off-topic :)

Comment: So is an answer that rotates statically instead of animating. Besides, it's customary to mark the duplicate answer so people can see the actual code

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise this wasn't for WPF

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of articles which explain how to rotate [Image](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations). You need some more customizations to keep it rotating while your form is loaded.

Just [download](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/RotatePictureBox/RotatePictureBoxSource.zip) the source code and add following piece of code in `Form1`. Start a new thread and call a function which keeps rotating the image.

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(KeepRotating);   // Kick off a new thread
            t.Start();
        }

       void KeepRotating()
        {
            for (float i = 1; i <= 360; i++)
            {
                RotateImage(pictureBox1, image, i);
                Thread.Sleep(20);  // for slower rotation, Avoid if not needed
                if (i == 360f)
                {
                    i = 1f;
                }
            }
        }
```

Output looks something like this.

[image]

P.S. This is a very simple and raw method to accomplish the task. Make sure you take care of exception handling and memory leaks.

Comment: Thanku it is working fine